# Barbarian Attack and Damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack

How do you calculate the attack and damage bonuses for a level 1 barbarian? Assume an 18 (+4) strength and the Power Attack & Weapon Focus (Greatsword) feats.

My attempt to do so is below, but I am not sure if this is correct.

**regular attack:** +6 atk, 2d6+6 dmg

**power attack:** +5 atk, 2d6+8 dmg

**power attack while raging:** +9 atk, 2d6+12 dmg

Comment: And you might want to edit this question to add interpunction at the very least, as it is a bit hard to understand right now. One of the mods might do it for you if they are feeling nice, but do it yourself, and save them the work! And welcome to the site, by the way.

Answer (score 11):

First case: The attack bonus is correct, +4 for strength, +1 BAB, +1 WF. The damage is also correct, 1-1/2 strength bonus. 
Second case, attack bonus is correct, but the damage is incorrect.

> You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls. This bonus to damage is increased by half (+50%) if you are making an attack with a two-handed weapon

(d20pfsrd.com)

This actually means that its supposed to be 2d6 + 9, as the bonus is +3.

Third case, your raging strength is 22. That is a +6 bonus, meaning +8 normal raging attack bonus, and +7 when power attacking. The damage is 2d6 + 12, just as stated.

- Greatsword +6, 2d6 + 6
- *Power attack:* Greatsword +5, 2d6 + 9
- *Rage, Power attack*: Greatsword +7, 2d6 + 12
- *Rage:* Greatsword + 8, 2d6 + 9

Correct (and downvote) me if I'm wrong, not exactly a PF expert

*Edit: I'll add how to calculate it for future reference:*

**Attack bonus**: That is your BAB + strength modifier + any feats and buffs

BAB: in the barbarian case, it is equal to your class level
Strength modifier: not 1-1/2. In ranged attacks, it is the Dex modifier.
Feats: In your case, Weapon Focus, although others may apply.

**The damage bonus**: your strength modifier (or 1-1/2 of it when fighting with two hands and a non-light weapon) + any relevant feat bonuses

Feat bonus, in your case is the Power attack, described above.

*Edit 2:*
As Rob noted in the comments, it is extremely helpful to have a character sheet when enraged, and when not. It means that you have all your stats written down, including the attacks, and you can just switch as you start raging.

Comment: I note (to help) that the barbarian in our party actually has two character sheets for himself; one in rage, one out, he says that helps a lot in tracking everything.

Comment: I'll edit that in, if you don't mind.